# List manipulation to extract values greater than current and remaining index values

Tags: python-2.7, list, if-statement, for-loop

I have following list:

`elev = [0.0, 632.8, 629.9, 626.5, 623.7, 620.7, 620.7, 607.4, 603.2, 602.0, 606.6, 613.2, 608.4, 599.7, 583.6]`

Ideally it should be in descending order but `602.0` is smaller than next 3 values `(606.6,613.2,608.4)` and I need a count of those values each time this issue arises. I am trying nested for loops to count those values with following:

```
l = len(et)    
for i in xrange(1,l-1,1):
    for j in xrange(1,l-1,1):
        if (et[i] < et[j]):
            print et[i]
```

But instead I get all values greater than `602.0`. How do I restrict loop to only count those 3 values? Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: is the first element always zero?

Comment: Your 607.4 entry is out of sequence (613.2 and 608.4 are larger), so you've got quite a number of inversions in the sequence.  How do you want to count inversions?  For 607.4, there are 2 larger values after it; for 603.2, there are 3; for 602.0, there are 3; for 606.6, there are 2.  So, should you be getting 10 counted (10 values printed)?

Comment: I want to keep the sequence. Only want to keep track of inversion which first meets criteria `et[i] < et[i+1]` i.e. `602.0`

Comment: @NinjaGaiden possible but not necessary

Comment: If you're doing such operations on larger lists, maybe consider using numpy? http://www.numpy.org/

Comment: @ShubhamNamdeo it was still giving me `606.6` loop values whereas I only needed `602.0` values. I am able to solve it differently and added that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l_elev = len(elev)
gt_cnt = 0
eq_cnt = 0
slp_idx = []
for i in xrange(1,l_elev-3,1):
    # following will take care of greater than current value inversion
    if elev[i+gt_cnt] < elev[i+1+gt_cnt]:
        lnew = elev[i+gt_cnt:]
        gt_inv = [y for y in lnew if y >= elev[i+gt_cnt]]
        gt_cnt += 1
        for x in xrange(i,i+len(gt_inv),1):
            slp_idx.append(x)

    # following will take care of adjacent equal values
    if (elev[i+eq_cnt] - elev[i+eq_cnt+1]) == 0:
        cnew = elev[i:]
        eq_inv = [y for y in cnew if y == elev[i+eq_cnt]]
        eq_cnt+=1
        for y in xrange(i,i+len(eq_inv),1):
            slp_idx.append(y)
    # break loop to avoid out of index error
    if i+gt_cnt > l_elev:
        break
```

Comment: upvoted your answer and question. you may do the same for my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will solve your problem:

```
l = len(et)    
for i in xrange(1,l-1,1):
    if et[i] < et[i+1]:
        for j in xrange(i,l-1,1):
            if (et[i] < et[j]):
                print et[j]
```

It will print the values greater than your number, not all but only the ones which came after the number.

This is what I've got from my terminal:

```
>>> for i in xrange(1,l-1,1):
...     if et[i] < et[i+1]:
...             print "for",et[i]
...             for j in xrange(i,l-1,1):
...                     if (et[i] < et[j]):
...                             print et[j]
...
for 602.0
606.6
613.2
608.4
for 606.6
613.2
608.4
```

Comment: count will vary if I use a different list so using `count < 3` isn't viable

Comment: I guess you need start your second loop from i then, check answer now.

Comment: it gives all greater values instead I need only ones greater than current and remaining index values

Comment: It is giving for the current values only. Wait let me add one more line so it will be much more clear for you.

Comment: @Ibe check answer now, it is printing only values which are greater than the current value of `et[i]`

Comment: I need only count of these:
`for 602.0
 606.6
 613.2
 608.4`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136203/discussion-between-shubham-namdeo-and-ibe).